# sort the results of array in alphabetical order in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am display the brand names with the count of brand number in an array,i want to sort them in alphabetical order.Following is the snippet

```
<?php
foreach($new_array as $BRAND => $n) {

?>
                        <li><input type="checkbox"  class="brand" value="<?php echo $BRAND; ?>" name="Brand"  
                id="roundedOne"  /><label for="roundedOne"><?php echo $BRAND;?> <span class="number_count"><?php echo "($n)"; ?></label></li>
                <?php

}
?>
```

How can i sort the list to be displayed in alphabetical order.This array is containing the brand names with their count in that..
Please guide me on this..

Comment: You can use `sort` functions in php before `foreach` statement. (`sort`, `usort`, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort it on $BRAND which means you want to sort it on the key. So use `ksort`.

Before the foreach just do `ksort($new_array);`

Answer (score -1):

Very simple, I think you want to sort it on $BRAND. So use sort() function. Before the foreach loop line just put this code **sort($new_array)** or see below code.

```
<?php
   $new_array = array("BB", "DD", "AA", "CC");
   sort($new_array); // New added line code.
   foreach($new_array as $BRAND => $n)
   {
      // Your displaying html + php code.
   }
?>
```